# with bash, is it possible to enter commands inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, shell, podman

i'm trying to see if i can run commands after "entering" into a container:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 1 - create a new user in the db for mautic

podman exec -it postal-mariadb mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p$1 <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE mauticdb;
        CREATE USER 'mautic' IDENTIFIED BY /'$1/';
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mauticdb.* TO 'mautic';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
        exit
EOF
```

this gives me an error: `Error: container create failed (no logs from conmon): EOF`

but im thinking maybe this is not a good use of `HERE DOCS`

something like this doesn't work either:

`echo $1 | podman exec -it postal-mariadb mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p postal-server-1 -e 'select * from deliveries limit 10;'`

Comment: I took the liberty to replace your _bash_ tag by the more appropriate _shell_ tag, since a bash doesn't seem to be involved here.

Comment: You shouldn't need any sort of `exec` command here; just run this `mysql` command from your host system connecting to the database's published port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fine (and common) use of here docs, although you probably want to drop the `-t` from your podman command line. If I have a mariadb container running:

```
podman run -d --name mariadb -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret docker.io/mariadb:10
```

Then if I put your shell script into a file named `createdb.sh`, modified to look like this for my environment:

```
podman exec -i mariadb mysql -u root -p$1 <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE mauticdb;
        CREATE USER 'mautic' IDENTIFIED BY '$1';
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mauticdb.* TO 'mautic';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
```

I've made three changes:

1. I've removed the `-t` from the `podman exec` command line, since we're passing input on stdin rather than starting an interactive terminal;
2. I removed the unnecessary `exit` command (the interactive mysql shell will exit when it reaches end-of-file);
3. I removed the weird forward slashes around your quotes (`/'$1/'` -> `'$1'`).

I can run it like this:

```
sh createdb.sh secret
```

And it runs without errors. The database exists:

```
$ podman exec mariadb mysql -u root -psecret -e 'show databases'
Database
information_schema
mauticdb   <--- THERE IT IS
mysql
performance_schema
sys
```

And the user exists:

```
$ podman exec mariadb mysql -u root -psecret mysql -e 'select user from user where user="mautic"'
User
mautic
```

Comment: thank you!  i also experimented with just passing an entire string after `-e`, is there a reason the here doc would be a better use?

Comment: I think using a here-doc makes it easier to manage quoting. I generally prefer it over embedding things in the command line. But these are all opinions!